# Gradle build failed with Gradle plug-in 7.1.1

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Android studio. All new project showing this error:

Build file '/Users/messan/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/build.gradle' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Google
  MavenRepo

Comment: add you both gradle

Comment: Add you `gradle.build` file please so we can help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. Files:

Build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "KospetWatchApp"
include ':app'
```

I have not altered anything in the project after creating a blank new project from Android Studio

Comment: Welcome to SO. This clearly and obviously do not attempt to answer an on-topic question or the question asked.